# Problem with surface integral of a scalar function

Tags: integration

I have difficulties in integrating this scalar function over the assigned surface. I've tried with the standard method but I always obtain an integral which I don't think can be solved.

Let $\Sigma=\{(x,y,z):(x-2y)^2+(y-x)^2=1,\,0\le x+y+2z\le1\}$

Calculate $\int_\Sigma xdS$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hints**:

Using the Divergence Theorem, we get $\displaystyle\iint\limits_{\Sigma}x\,dS = \iiint\limits_{V}1\,dV$ where $V = \{(x,y,z) : (x-2y)^2+(y-x)^2 \le 1, 0 \le x+y+2z \le 1\}$.

To evaluate this integral, first use the substitution $u = x-2y$, $v = y-x$, $z = z$.

Then, convert the resulting integral to cylindrical coordinates.

Comment: Thanks, I tried elaborating on this and I think I got it right.

Comment: Are you dure the divergence theorem is applied correctly vere? A couple of colleagues told me it's wrong.